# JPA Native Query with IN statement

Tags: sql, spring-boot, jpa

I am trying to use nativeQuery in springboot JPA

```
Query(value = "select * from sms.outgoing_message where create_ts between timestamp(?1) and timestamp(?2) and (error_code IN (?3) or (error_code = '0' and error_msg not like '%Opt out%') or (error_code = '1' and (error_msg like '%21211%' or error_msg like '%21612%' or error_msg = 'Mobile number format is wrong')))", nativeQuery = true)
  List<OutgoingMessage> getBounceBackPhoneNumbers(LocalDateTime from, LocalDateTime to, List<String> listSoftBounceErrorCodes);
```

Above query returns empty result.

when I try error codes like 30008,30005,30007,30003,30006 instead of ?3 it gives me more results

Any idea what could be the issue?

Comment: There could be more than one record which a given code you are binding to your query.  Or, there could be a syntax problem.

Comment: I suspect your timestamp part is not being passed correctly, can you put here calling code

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `LocalDate` or `LocalDateTime` with JPA, you need to define the mapping to java.sql.Date or java.sql.Timestamp yourself.

In you case, the conversion between a LocalDateTime and a java.sql.Timestamp is done with the conversion methods of Timestamp.

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.sql.Timestamp;

@Converter(autoApply = true)
public class LocalDateTimeAttributeConverter implements AttributeConverter<LocalDateTime, Timestamp> {

    @Override
    public Timestamp convertToDatabaseColumn(LocalDateTime locDateTime) {
        return locDateTime == null ? null : Timestamp.valueOf(locDateTime);
    }

    @Override
    public LocalDateTime convertToEntityAttribute(Timestamp sqlTimestamp) {
        return sqlTimestamp == null ? null : sqlTimestamp.toLocalDateTime();
    }
}
```

reference : [persist-localdate-localdatetime-jpa](https://thoughts-on-java.org/persist-localdate-localdatetime-jpa/)

Comment: if I hard code  listSoftBounceErrorCodes / ?3 it works fine, so dont think there is problem with lodaldatetime. I think problem with with 'IN' statement with list<string> passed